# ARCore 1.0 on S8 (SM-G950F). Apps crashing

Tags: galaxy, arcore

I've updated my S8 to Oreo some days ago and installed the 1.0 release of ARCore through the play store. Now apps that are supposed to support 1.0 (Atom Visualizer) and HelloAR updated to 1.0 are crashing or not showing the camera image.
Is there a known problem with Oreo on S8 devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue on the S8/S8+ and OnePlus 5:
[ARCore GitHub Issues](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/198)

There is supposedly a fix in an upcoming release. No indication of an ETA though.